# Animating Bootstrap Open and close animation - angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm using twitter bootstrap modal window in angular and wanted to have animations when the modal window shows up and when it is closed. I tried nganimate but it doesn't seem to work.

CSS

```
.slide-enter-setup, .slide-leave-setup {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}
.slide-enter-setup {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:-200px;
}

.slide-enter-start {
  top:0;
}

.slide-leave-setup {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.slide-leave-start {
  top:200px;
}
```

JS

```
angular.module("template/modal/window.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/modal/window.html",
    "<div ng-animate=\"slide\" class=\"modal{{ windowClass }}\" ng-class=\"{in: animate}\" ng-style=\"{'z-index': 1050 + index*10}\" ng-transclude></div>");
}]);
```

Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/D1tMRpxVzn51g18Adnp8?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You're using AngularJS 1.2.x, but your CSS code follows the older convention. Read this article and update your CSS code: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html